# XML parsing options-php or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I want to create a simple site to display records from an xml file about butterflies. I think the requirements are simple. Search by one node(i.e. color, length,etc.). I know I could probably use php and simpleXML. But what about jQuery? Would I be able to show all records that have black in the color node of each record? I suspect that there will be no more than about 400 records. At this point also I do not need any "backend" I will just edit the xml files manually.

My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Butterflies>
  <Butterfly submitter="lildog">
    <CommonName>Monarch</CommonName>
    <LatinName>Something Latiny</LatinName>
    <MainColor>black</MainColor>
    <Date>12/3/2011</Date>
  </Butterfly>
  <Butterfly submitter="lildog">
    <CommonName>Admiral</CommonName>
    <LatinName>Something Latiny</LatinName>
    <MainColor>red</MainColor>
    <Date>12/3/2011</Date>
  </Butterfly>
</Butterflies>
```

Any thoughts much appreciated

Todd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.get("path/to/xml/file.xml")
    .success(function(xmlData) {
        var elem = "#element_id_to_put_in"; //actually you can use any css3 selector
        $(xmlData).find("[color=black]").each(function() {
             $(elem).append($(this).html());
        });
    })
    .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("error");
    });
```

Comment: That works very well for attributes. How would you get all records that have the MainColor child as black using the xml I added above?

Comment: That is excellent! One last question...how to display the CommonName of butterflies that are maincolor black? This does not work:             $(xml).find("MainColor:contains('black')").each(function() {
         $("#output").append($(this).find("CommonName").text());
});